# Adjusting estimated true mean and standard deviations by comparing two truncated normal distributions

Tags: probability, truncated-normal-distribution

I am trying to compare two truncated normal distributions, by estimating unknown mean and standard deviation from truncated distributions. One example is men and women competing in a certain sports event. Only results above a set cutoff threshold (same for both and women) are registered for each competition, resulting in truncated distributions.

But as the mean of the female distribution is lower, a larger population is truncated.

I have estimated the true mean and standard deviation via the tables starting on page 5 in [Simplified Estimators for the Normal Distribution When Samples Are Singly Censored or Truncated](https://www.stat.cmu.edu/technometrics/59-69/VOL-01-03/v0103217.pdf).

But as can be seen in the following chart, I believe the resulting normal distribution is not precise enough. Which is understandable considering the spikes (basically at rounded results).

[image]

The distribution curve is expected to cross the vertical axis at a positive value (due to a small percentage of the total population unable to realize any performance). Let's say I set the value of *c*, where the curve crosses Y at X = 0, to 0.001.

Could I then adjust the standard deviation and/or the mean, with the prerequisite that *c* has to be 0.001?

In the end the aim is to consider a cumulative probability in one distribution to be equal to the same cumulative probability in another (both across genders and events).

I'm working in R, so R code to solve my issue is welcome. :D

Comment: I now found a way to use R to estimate the unknown mean and standard deviation of the parent normal distribution: fitdist from the fitdistrplus package. 

`fitdist(data, "truncnorm", fix.arg = list(a = 0.7), start = list(mean = 1.54, sd = 0.23))`

Still, the spikes are likely impacting the calculations, in order to get the true mean and sd. Is it even possible to estimate?